# show multi-line text value in cells of an XML excel document made with C# XmlWriter

Tags: c#, xml, excel, export-to-excel, multiline

The Situation: I'm creating a C# .Net 4.0 Winform to collect a datatable from an Oracle DB using filters chosen by the user and putting them into a Gridview Preview to check out. Once they have filtered the data to their liking they click an export button which converts the datatable into an XML document that opens in Excel when double clicked. Inside the XML excel file each record looks like so:

```
  <ss:Row>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="General">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">110002</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="General">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">GALV.047M X 3 G90 A653 PASSDRY SQ GR33</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
    <ss:Cell ss:StyleID="General">
      <ss:Data ss:Type="String">.047 MIN X 3 X COIL
!GALV G90 ASTM A 653 SQ GR33 PASS DRY*

20" ID
5 TON MAX LIFT
SKID EYE TO THE SKY
3" X 3" SPACER IN BETWEEN EACH BUNDLE
SUPPLY TEST REPORTS CHEMICAL</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
  </ss:Row>
```

Which displays records in excel similar to how you would seem them if the file were a CVS, a completly unformatted worksheet with all text on a single line. Clearly inside the XML file the line breaks are preserved, but the excel sheet is meant for users to edit the data so I need to display the text how I recieve it (ie. on multiple lines if that is the case).

The Question: How can I format the exported XML file to display it's cell contents on multiple lines (and perhaps increase cell hight to match) if that is how the data in the XML file is formatted?

Comment: using writer.WriteCData() in C# instead of writer.WriteValue() did the trick!

Answer (score 4):

If you create a simple Excel file with some multi-line contant and save as XML you can  see this in the output:

In the  tag

```
<Style ss:ID="s62">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
</Style>
```

Cell XML:

`<Cell ss:StyleID="s62">
    <Data ss:Type="String">First Line&#10;Second Line&#10;Last Line</Data>
  </Cell>`

Comment: so in my c# program i insert my styles like so:

 _writer.WriteStartElement("Styles", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");

            WriteExcelStyleElement(CellStyle.General);
            WriteExcelStyleElement(CellStyle.Number, "General Number");
            WriteExcelStyleElement(CellStyle.DateTime, "General Date");
            WriteExcelStyleElement(CellStyle.Currency, "Currency");
            WriteExcelStyleElement(CellStyle.ShortDate, "Short Date");

            _writer.WriteEndElement();

how would I change that to add the style you mentioned?

Comment: Also, when I add lines to the XML cells and I have a string like :

Firstline
SecondLine
lastLine

how do I add &#10; to that instead of \n? I have tghe following line:

ToValid = ToValid.Replace("\n", "\n&#10;\n");

but the ampersands in the resulting XML get turned into &amp;

Comment: Please post code by updating your question: it's much easier to read than in comments.

Comment: I found that I had to use &#13; which is a carriage return "\r" instead of &#10;, which is a new line "\n".